# Why doesn't Parsec backtrack when one part of the parser succeeds and the rest fails?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have this parsec parser :

```
a = optionMaybe $ do {try $ spaceornull *> string "hello";string "No"}
```

Where `spaceornull` is `((:[]) <$> try space) <|> string ""`

When I test a with input " " I get :

> Left (line 1, column 2):
>     unexpected end of input
>     expecting "hello"

I don't understand this, `spaceornull *> string "hello"` should fail because there is no "hello", then with `try` parsec backtracks and now there is no consumed input but `try` fails anyway so the parser passed to `optionMaybe` (the one inside `do`) fails altogether, it shouldn't try to consume farther input, so we end up with a failed parser without consuming any input so I should get `Right Nothing`.

But the error message says it, the space is consumed so `try` didn't really backtrack, does `try` not backtrack when part of parser succeeds ? and how to make it backtrack with the above ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`try` has nothing to do with whether failure is allowed or not. It merely makes it *possible* to backtrack in case of failure<sup>†</sup>, but to commence the backtracking you need to provide an alternative parser to start at that point. The usual way to do that is with the [`<|>` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-):

```
a = optionMaybe $ (try $ spaceornull *> string "hello") <|> string "No"
```

OTOH, your code is equivalent to

```
a = optionMaybe $ (try $ spaceornull *> string "hello") >> string "No"
```

where the monadic chaining [operator `>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:-62--62-) (same as [`*>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-)) will in the case of parsec check if the LHS succeeds, *then* go on and also run the RHS parser. So it must be, because you could also write:

```
a = optionMaybe $ do
       s <- try $ spaceornull *> string "hello"
       string $ "No"++s
```

Here I've used the result of the first parser (which you simply threw away, by not `<-`-matching it to any variable) in deciding *what* the second one should look for. This clearly is only possible of the first actually succeeded!

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Basically, `<|>` only works if either the LHS *immediately* fails right at the first character, or if you set a backtracking point with `try`. The reason this is required is that it would be very inefficient if parsec would need to leave a backtracking point before each and every alternative that needs to be ckecked.</sub>

Comment: good answer but If I replace `string "No"` with `"return "No"`(something that always succeeds) it doesn't backtrack even with `<|>` when `spaceornull` succeeds

Comment: Well, yes... `<|>` only considers the RHS parser if the LHS fails without consuming input. So?

Comment: what about `try` ? I mean `(try $ spaceornull *> string "hello") <|> (return "No")` shouldn't fail with input `" "` !!!

Comment: Correct, it doesn't fail but yields `"No"`.