# Propagation of (Mega)Parsec errors through continuations

Tags: haskell, parsec, megaparsec

I have a somewhat techinical question about the inner workings of (Mega)Parsec, the informal context of which is:

> What is the idea governing the accumulation/propagation of error messages through continuations in `Parsec`?

Specifically:
Consider the `mplus` operation making `ParsecT` an instance of `MonadPlus`.
([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#line-362))
`mplus m n` takes, as input, a string `s` to parse and continuations `cok`, `cerr`, `eok`, and `eerr` to follow based on the result of the parse.

First parse `s` with `m`:

- If the parse succeeds and consumes (respectively, does not consume) part of `s`, follow the `cok` (respectively, `eok`) continuation.
- If the parse of `s` with `m` fails while consuming part of `s`, follow the `cerr` continuation.
- Suppose the parse of `s` with `m` fails without consuming anything; let `err` be the parse error associated with this failure. We then try parsing `s` with `n`, and choose a continuation accordingly:

  - If the parse of `s` with `n` succeeds while consuming input, follow the `cok` continuation.
  - If the parse of `s` with `n` fails while consuming input, follow the `cerr` continuation.
  - If the parse of `s` with `n` succeeds without consuming input, follow a continuation `neok` derived from `eok`: `neok y s' err' = eok y s' (mergeError err err')`
  - If the parse of `s` with `n` fails without consuming input, follow a continuation `neerr` derived from `eerr`: `neerr y s' err' = eerr (mergeError err err')`

My question is:

> Why do we merge errors when following an 'empty' continuation and not when following a 'consumed' continuation, thereby forgetting about all previous errors?

This must be a design decision, but I can't figure out the reasoning behind it. Is there, perhaps, a simple example that would clarify this?

Comment: I think this is meant to achieve the effect of reporting all errors iff none of the attempted parsers succeeded; but if at least one succeeded, the errors from all unsuccessful parsers ought to be swallowed.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Then why does `cok` even take a `ParseError` argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057940/why-doesnt-parsec-backtrack-when-one-part-of-the-parser-succeeds-and-the-rest-f

Comment: @leftaroundabout Would you be able to guide me a little? What part of the referenced post is addressing what?

Comment: @fmg it takes that argument, because its signature is dictated by the `ParsecT` constructor.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I meant, why is the ParsecT type defined in this way, i.e., with cok taking a ParseError argument that never seems to be used nontrivially.

Comment: Because it's not in every case that you want up swallow these errors.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Would you mind suggesting an example where you don't want these elements swallowed when passing through `cok`? Are there any such in the `Parsec` codebase, that you know of?